# Não consigo acessar minha base de dados MySQL MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, mariadb, deepin

Estou no Linux Deepin 15.19 e instalei para Desenvolvimento Web, no entanto quando nao consigo criar novas bases de dados pelo MySql Worckbench por diz:

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306:
>     Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>
> Please:
>   1 Check that mysql is running on server localhost
>   2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
>   3 Check the root has rights to connect to localhost from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
>   4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for localhost connecting from the host address you're connecting from

Eu Ja tentei desinstalar, fiz de tudo. Tentei mudar a senha pelo comando

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

e logo após

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '1234';
```

e nem isso resolve, o que tenho é um erro.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '1234'' at line 1

Estou precisando muito da sua ajuda pois meu desenvolvimento depende disso.

Comment: Mateus, o servidor está na mesma maquina em que o workbench se encontra?

Comment: Tenta colocar a senha do root do mysql igual a senha root da sua máquina.

Comment: Ué, MySQL e MariaDB não são SGBDs diferentes? Afinal você está rodando MySQL ou MariaDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, pelas mensagens parece ser problema com o o usuário e senha, vi que essa distro é baseada no debian então creio que seja igual:

1 - Parar o processo do mysql:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

2 - Reinicia o processo do mysql, não verificando as permissões das tabelas:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

3 - Acessar o cliente mysql

```
 mysql -u root
```

4 - Executar o comando abaixo para poder trocar qualquer senha:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

5 - Então troca a senha do root

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('senha');
```

6 -  Atualiza os privilégios:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Reinicia o mysql no modo padrão:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comandos retirados e adaptados de https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Comment: Obrigado, mas não resolveu no comando 5 da um erro 
>SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('4321');
ERROR 1131 (42000): You are using MariaDB as an anonymous user and anonymous users are not allowed to modify user settings

Answer (score 0):

Tenta abrir seu terminal e usar o comando

```
mysql -u root -p
```

este comando vai solicitar a senha do seu mysql após digitar deve acessar o mysql pelo terminal. Caso acesse normalmente o erro está em alguma configuração do seu workbench. Caso não acesse normalmente o erro está na instalação do seu mysql tente desinstalar e instalar novamente e efetue o mesmo teste mais uma vez e certifique-se de digitar a senha corretamente.